# Post hoc comparisions in many groups

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model, interaction

I met such problem. I have measured the respiration of animals in  in 5 time intervals. Within each interval I have animals asigned to 4 treatments. In my main analysis I consider both: treatment and interval as fixed categorical factors. I obtained significant interaction. I'd like to check now post hoc which groups are differing. If I use classical post hoc tests I make many unnecessary comparisions (I have 20 groups in such scenario) between treatment from variuos intervals what decreases power of the test and does not interest me. I'd like to ask if that is any solution of that problem? I thought about Dunnett's test, but there I would compare everything with control group (what decreases number of possible outcomes and does not meet hypotheses I'd like to test). I'd like to compare treatments in one interval, but do not compare treatments between intervals. So far I do not know any procedure to do it. 
I also tried to find proper test to compare all groups pairwise but do not loose the power of the test. I've done already Tukey, Fisher (but than I learned that this test is rather of hictorical use) and Duncan tests. I read that quite good is Ryan's test (powerfull but roboust to type I error), but I cannot find any procedure to do that in R for lmer class objects (I have random factors as well in the model). 
I'd be very grateful for any help.

Comment: Am I correct that you have 4 groups of animals, subjected to different treatments? Measured at 5 different times?

Comment: I have 4 groups of animals (treatments which is predator pressure) measured in 5 time intervals. The machine can measure the respiration in time intervals of some duration (ca 2h). My R model is:
respiro.lmer<-lmer(o2~Int*zab+ (1|dzi/komora),"REML"=T,data=by)
Where o2 is o2 consumption rate, Int is interval, zab is treatment, dzi is day of measurement and komora is particular individual (measured 5 times).

Tahnk you for the message!